# Echo HTML not working because of double quote?

Tags: php, getuikit

I know that in this code:

```
 echo '<button style="width:100%;"class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:#my-id'}">Kurstermine anzeigen</button>';
```

this: `data-uk-modal="{target:#my-id'}"` causes that any other code below won't run. But how can I fix it? I already tried fixing it by adding `\` before the `"` but this doesn't change the behavior of the error.

Comment: the problem is the `'` at `#my-id'`.

Comment: remove quotes, change to ` echo '<button style="width:100%;"class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:#my-id}">Kurstermine anzeigen</button>';`

Comment: 1) The single quote messes up the flow, but adding the slash before it should work. 2) Your HTML would still be messed up because you're missing the matching single quote.

Comment: Remove the echo ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: @wayneOS Yes, there was even a missing one before the `#`. Fixed by adding a `\` before the `#my-id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

echo <<<EOT
        <button style="width:100%;"class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:#my-id'}">Kurstermine anzeigen</button> 

EOT;
```

Comment: it's not duplicate.

Comment: It is. HEREDOC is mentioned in the accepted answer as well.

Comment: <?php if ($expression == true): ?>
    <button style="width:100%;"class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:#my-id'}">Kurstermine anzeigen</button> 
 
<?php endif; ?>